# can not set parameters for JRE in control panel for Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: java, environment-variables

This is a weird problem.   On one of our demo machines running Windows 7, we are trying to increase the amount of memory allocated to the heap.    I open the Java control panel.  Click on the Java tab and the click the View button.   I type -Xmx256m in the Runtime Parameters fields.   Then click OK.    So far so good.   However, if I navigate away from the tab and then navigate back, the parameters that I just typed disappear.    Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be done from JRE control panel but you can create environment variable with name '_JAVA_OPTS' and set any java parameters there (-Xmx256m). This will be picked up by any java process started on that computer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Win 7 64 bit, but had the same problem.  This solution worked for me:

1. After typing your values in the Runtime Parameters field, click 'OK'
2. After the settings dialog disappears, click 'Apply' in the main control panel dialog.

If you click 'View...' again, you'll see the setting now appears.